# Questions about Notation Used in Dirac Equation:

Tags: notation, physics

Following the notation used in David J. Griffiths *Introduction to Elementary Particles*, recall that $a^{\mu}b_{\mu}:=a^{0}b^{0}-a^{1}b^{1}-a^{2}b^{2} - a^{3}b^{3}$. Recall the relativistic Dirac equation 
$$
i\hbar\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi = mc \psi
$$
In this case, our notational definition above does *not* hold, in that
$$
\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} = \gamma^{0}\partial_{0} + \gamma^{1}\partial_{1} + \gamma^{2}\partial_{2} + \gamma^{3}\partial_{3}.
$$
Why is this?

Note that the Dirac equation as given above derives from 
$$
\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi = mc \psi
$$
where the convention above *does* hold, in that 
$
\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} = \gamma^{0}p^{0} - \gamma^{1}p^{1}-\gamma^{2}p^{2}-\gamma^{3}p^{3}
$
then the quantum substitution $p_{\mu}\to i\hbar\partial_{\mu}$ (is this right?) is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct if you remember that

$${\bf p}=-i\nabla$$

and

$$p_0=i\partial_t.$$

Then, if you put this in $\gamma^{0}p_{0} - \gamma^{1}p_{1} - \gamma^{2}p_{2} - \gamma^{3}p_{3}$ you will get immediately the result that is also in agreement with the definition of $\partial_\mu$, that is $\partial_\mu=(\partial_t,-\nabla)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is all explained in chapter 3.2, notably equation 3.16 $x_{\mu}=g_{\mu\nu} x^{\nu}$, where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! That's exactly what I had missed. If you don't mind me asking, is $p_{\mu} \to i\hbar\partial_{\mu}$ (eq. 7.5) a typo? I was under the impression that (say) $p_{1} \to -i\hbar\partial_{1}$.